# help searching and selling an item on the net

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask my fellow SE-ers for help searching for some sunglasses according to a photo.

Is there any SE site where I can post my question?

Comment: No, there isn't. I don't expect there will ever be.

Comment: Google has such feature for some time now. Go to the Images tab of Google and click the small camera icon to the right of the textbox (left in case of Hebrew) - you will be able to upload a photo or post URL of existing photo and Google will give you similar images and websites containing those images.

Comment: We get spam posts from people *selling* sunglasses. Perhaps you could check those out?

Answer (score 6):

The goal of Stack Exchange is to provide the best Question & Answer sites on different topics on the web.

A site where people post photos and ask for help finding the items on it doesn't really sound like it will progress that goal.